# Position absolute to a non-parent container

Tags: css

I have the following div:

```
<div id="container"></div>
<img id="myimg" src="myimage.jpg" />
```

I need to place an image to an absolute position to the top and left of the container, however my image can not be placed inside the container:

```
img
{
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  left: 15px;
}
```

How can I amend the image css to achieve this?

Comment: That depends very much on the DOM structure, and the other formatting already applied. Please create a [mcve] of the situation you need this to work in.

Comment: your div doesn't have an `<img>` tag. and why is there no = after id? it should be `id="container"`. can oyu please update your html and css to a working example?

Comment: Why can it not be inside the container? Please show your example in more detail.

Comment: @Kyon147 it is a dynamically created div. I can't manually place it inside

Comment: How is it dynamically created? You should be able to access it if it is being created on your website. That way you can choose where it goes if you are using javascript for example.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the pic absolute and the parent div relative if you want img position to be inside the div, in that way top, left etc will start from the start of the parent div instead of the body.

I hope this answers your question, I'm not sure if I understood you correctly.

Comment: Yes but the image can't be placed inside the div

Comment: What do u mean it cant be placed? How exactly r u trying to place it there? Can u post an example here?

Comment: It is a dynamically created div. I don't have access to the code

Comment: Then, if you know the div exists you can just select it and dynamically inject the img with innerHTML or anything similar depending on what you are using vanilla js/jquery/some framework

Comment: I am using JQuery. This sounds like what I need

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the div you DON'T control inside a div that you do. Give the div you control position: relative and the image position: absolute. The inner div that you don't control will force the height/width of the one that you do.

```
<div id="containerYouControl">
     <div id="container">
     </div>
     <img id="myimg" src="myimage.jpg" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer with JQuery:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function() { 

  var html ='<div id="animaBorder" style="left: 250px; top: 20px;"><img src="myimage.jpg" /></div>';

  $("#container").append(html );

  });

 </script>
```